# DrawerLayout: dismiss keyboard by tapping home icon in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-softkeyboard, drawerlayout

I'm using `DrawerLayout` in my app. I've attached `ActionBarDrawerToogle` to it. When keyborad is visible I still can call drawer menu. I don't want to. I want my app to behave like Youtube app so when keyboard appears there is no drawer toogle in action bar instead it has "home as up" button which dismisses the keyboard. While `ActionBarDrawerToogle` handles configuration changing events I though it would do it by default but it's not. How can I achieve this behavior?

[image: My app: can call drawer layout while keyboard is visible]
[image: My app: can call drawer layout while keyboard is visible]
[image: Play Store: while keyboard is visible tapping home button will dismiss the keyboard]
[image: Play Store: while keyboard is visible tapping home button will dismiss the keyboard]

Comment: can you attach screen shots for behavior you want and the behavior you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know how to do it. `SearchView` have to be added as menu item like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/projects_menu_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
```

The key is that it is set as `actionView` and `icon` is set too. After tapping on icon actionView  become visible and "up" button also appear. Tapping on "up" button collapses actionView.

Answer (score 0):

In `onResume` of home activity you can hide keyboard by:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score -1):

## Dismiss keyboard like this

If you want to just dismiss it you can use the following lines of code in your button's on click Event

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: This is an answer for another question which was asked on SO many times.

Comment: You wanted code to dismiss the keyboard on clicking the "home as up" button. If you don't play nice, start down voting without being clear, no one is going to help you around here.

Comment: Look at the title: I didn't ask how to dismiss the keyboeard in general. You gave me general answer which can be easily found on SO. While you didn't help you also though I'm not able to find this simple answer myself.